# Filtrar busca por software

Tags: suporte

Espero que está minha pergunta seja pertinente nesta comunidade, mas enfim...

Sou usuário do software Mathematica. Tenho algumas perguntas no site em inglês e aqui no site em português o foco é mais para Java, Python, ..., que não é meu forte.

A pergunta é a seguinte:

Tem como filtrar as perguntas que são do software Mathematica?

Algo do tipo `[mathematica]` para colocar no search...

Comment: Só complementando a resposta: O site não tem um "foco" necessariamente, quando o assunto é programação. Qualquer linguagem, IDE ou plataforma é bem vinda. Se você tem interesse em mais perguntas sobre Mathematica aqui, fale com outras pessoas a respeito, pergunte aqui também.

Comment: @Gabe Pelo que vejo você é moderador. Se não tiver a tag Mathematica eu poderia criá-la? Sem que atrapalhe os outros usuários

Comment: Criar uma tag nunca vai atrapalhar os outros, necessariamente. Como o bigown falou, elas são usadas pra organizar o site e permitir que você filtre as perguntas pelos assuntos que tem interesse. O SOen, por exemplo, tem uma [tag sobre Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica), bem movimentada. Quanto à criação de tags, são necessários 300 pontos, mas um dos moderadores pode criar se for o caso.

Comment: @Gabe Pergunto isso porque se existir esta tag eu irei editar as perguntas que eu encontrar. Mas vou fazer com cautela porque já levei um baita puxão de orelha no outro site por editar demais.

Comment: Depende do tipo da edição. Mas se quiser trazer conteúdo seu do Mathematica pra cá, sem problema nenhum. Recomendo só convidar mais gente porque, atualmente, não tenho muita certeza de que tem gente no site que mexe com isso `:)`

Comment: @Gabe Pois é. Não sei se vai ter muita gente respondendo aqui em português. Mas agradeço a idéia e farei um teste. Pode ser que mais usuários se interessem.

Comment: @Gabe Como tenho algumas  respondidas, você acha que seria uma boa conduta perguntar e eu mesmo responder com a intenção de fazer algum tipo de migração?

Comment: Sem problema algum perguntar e responder você mesmo. Só recomendo dar um tempo (1 ou 2 dias) pra ver se aparece outra pessoa pra responder. Você pode se surpreender com soluções diferentes, e ajudar a iniciar uma subcomunidade aqui no site.

Comment: @Gabe Ok. Vou fazer um teste. Se você é moderador, você poderia me adiantar a tag Mathematica?

Comment: Faça uma pergunta primeiro. Tags não podem ser criadas sem estar associadas à nenhuma pergunta

Comment: @Gabe http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172960/importando-arquivos-dxf-e-manipulando-com-mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teria se existisse alguma pergunta com essa *tag*.

Como o sistema de classificação das perguntas é de *tags*, basta clicar em qualquer uma delas e poderá ver tudo o que tem lá. Pode fazer buscas compostas também.

Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Todas as *tags*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags

Em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search clique em "Pesquisa Avançada" para ver todas as opções disponíveis.